# How to publish Pentaho report using sql db?

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-report-designer

We are using the Pentaho report designer together with MS SQL DB. We want to publish the report. When we publishing the report we are getting a **"Fatal parameter passing information error"** .

When I use PostgresSQL and query then it is working and the report is published fine.

Please let me know how to publish a report using MS SQL and query.

Comment: Do you have the correct JDBC drivers installed on your PRD/lib ?

Comment: yes, i have kept these files in pentaho/report-designer/lib path: sqljdbc4-3-.0.jar, mysql-2_0_12.jar,jdbc-mssql.jar.  after that i have restart the server , even though it is showing same error , please let me know the solution

Comment: publish means running the report or publishing into BI Server?